# How to select x level deep JSON data with Python

Tags: python, json, rest

I am trying to select data with python from what I believe is formatted in JSON. I am using this for loop to select the data as so.

```
for line_item in response['response']:
   print(line_item['name'] + ', ' + line_item['orderId'])
```

But how would I also select impressionsDelivered so the output is 1234?

```
(LineItem){
          orderId = 123456
          name = "fooname"
          stats = (Stats){
                    impressionsDelivered = 1234
                    clicksDelivered = 1234
                    }
```

Comment: is your response a json?

Comment: I think it may be. I'm using the google API to pull data from DFP.

Comment: then print(line_item['stats']['impressionsDelivered']) should work or are you looking for a more generic way to do it?

Comment: @YOBA That worked great. Thanks! can you tell me why that worked?

Comment: Ok I'll post a detailed response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have this json called response (to use your example):

```
response = {
          "response":    [   # start of a list of elements
                   {         # start of the 1st element
          "orderId" : 123456,
          "name" : "fooname",
          "stats" : {
                    "impressionsDelivered" : 1234,
                    "clicksDelivered" : 1234
                    }},      # end of the 1st element
                    {        # start of the 2nd element
          "orderId" : 1234565,
          "name" : "fooname2",
          "stats" : {
                    "impressionsDelivered" : 12345,
                    "clicksDelivered" : 12345
                    }}      # end of the second element
                          ] # end of the list
             }
```

A json is a dictionary like format with keys and values
its written: `{key:value}`

and a value can be itself compose of keys and values
example: `key: {key2:value2}`  , {key2:value2} being the value of key

How to access them:
You access a dictionary by the keys

in the json above, if I want to access all the values of response:

```
print( response["response"] )
```

if you want a deep access to the next element, which is orderId, notice the bracket opening '[' which tells you a list starts:

```
print( response["response"][0] ) # first element of the list
print( response["response"][0]["orderId"] ) # access orderId
```

You access a dictionary by its key and a list by its index

Tip: Use Ipython and paste this code to practice

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with REST. Just grab your raw response (presumably in JSON format, as you indicated), and then paste it into any [online json viewer](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS705US705&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=json+online+viewer&*), then you should be able to figure out how to navigate to the item you want.